# Issues Passing State to Another Page Using Link Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

I'm working on passing the state (recipe information) of each recipe found in an API to another component called RecipePage.jsx. After the API call is made, the arrayof information is mapped so that when I select a loaded recipe, it will take me to a dedicated page for each one. However, I am getting an error in RecipePage about the value recipe being null.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'recipe' of 'location.state' as it is null.

Source Code is below

SearchBar.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {FaSearch} from "react-icons/fa";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./SearchBar.css";

function SearchBar() {
    const [input, setInput] = useState("");
    const [searchList, setSearchList] = useState();
    const [listLoaded, setListLoaded] = useState(false);
    const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
        }
    };

    const handleChange = (value) => {
        setInput(value);
    }

    const keyHandler = (e) => {
        if(e.code === "Enter") {
            fetchData(input);
        }
    }


    const fetchData = (value) => {
        let queryString = new URLSearchParams(value).toString();
        const url = `https://food-recipes-with-images.p.rapidapi.com/?q=${queryString}`;
        fetch(url, options)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
                setSearchList(data['d']);
                if (!data['d']) {
                    console.log("The request failed");
                } else {
                    setListLoaded(true);
                    console.log(data['d']);
                }
            })
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <div className="input-wrapper">
                <FaSearch id="search-icon" />
                <input placeholder="Search" value={input} onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target.value)} onKeyPress={(e) => keyHandler(e)} />
            </div>

            <div className="search-result-body">
                {listLoaded && searchList.map((item) => 
                    <Link
                            key={item.id}
                            to={{
                                pathname: `/recipe-item/${encodeURIComponent(item.Title)}`,
                                state: { recipe: item }
                            }}
                            className="recipe-link">
                        <div className="search-result-item">
                            <img src={item.Image} />
                            <p>{item.Title}</p>
                        </div>
                    </Link>
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default SearchBar;
```

App.jsx

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar/Navbar.jsx';
import Dashboard from "./components/Dashboard/Dashboard.jsx";
import Inventory from './components/Inventory/Inventory.jsx';
import MealPlanner from './components/MealPlanner/MealPlanner.jsx';
import Profiles from './components/Profiles/Profiles.jsx';
import Recipes from './components/Recipes/Recipes.jsx';
import RecipePage from './pages/RecipePage/RecipePage.jsx';
import './App.css'

function App() {
  

  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Navbar />
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />} />
            <Route path="/inventory" element={<Inventory />} />
            <Route path="/mealplanner" element={<MealPlanner />} />
            <Route path="/profiles" element={<Profiles/>} />
            <Route path="/recipes" element={<Recipes />} />
            <Route path="/recipe-item/:title" element={<RecipePage />} />
          </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>

    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

RecipePage.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

function RecipePage() {
    const location = useLocation();
    const { recipe } = location.state || {};
    console.log(recipe);

    if (!recipe) {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>No recipe data found!</p>
            </div>
        );
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>{recipe.Title}</h2>
        </div>
    );
}

export default RecipePage;
```

I've tried using navigate() and UrlParams to pass state but that hasn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem.

You've used `react-router-v6` as I can see in App.jsx.

But react-router-v6 doesn't allow this syntax anymore.

Wrong Syntax:

```
<Link
   key={item.id}
   to={{
      pathname: `/recipe-item/${encodeURIComponent(item.Title)}`,
      state: { recipe: item }
   }}
   className="recipe-link"
>
```

Correct Syntax:

```
<Link
   key={item.id}
   to={`/recipe-item/${encodeURIComponent(item.Title)}`}
   state: { recipe: item }
   className="recipe-link"
>
```

Pass `state` as a separate prop. [Details](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5#pass-link-state-as-separate-prop)

I hope it helps.